# How to batch edit images with specific editing task e.g. deleting a specific part?

Tags: batch, images, gimp

I want to edit a set of images. These edit consist of

- deleting a specific part (erasing a part e.g. making it transparent)
- adding a gradient at a certain area
- drawing on the images

all images have the same resolution.

I was saw that there is a gimp batch mode but this is mostly used to resize. what other options are there.

Comment: Just a comment, but for processing images in bulk, you may want to have a look at [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) as an alternative to GIMP for some or all of your operations.

Comment: What do you mean by :deleting a specific part"? Crop, clone spot, heal spot, content aware fill?

Comment: @Anaksunaman that could well be an answer. If you posted your suggestion along with [an example of what it can do and perhaps even how](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) then it could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like Anaksunaman said you could use ImageMagick.

- deleting a specific part (erasing a part e.g. making it transparent)

Here is an example:
`convert logo.jpg \( -size 640x480 xc:white -size 200x200 xc:black -geometry +200+100 -compose over -composite \) +geometry -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png`

Check out [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970937/how-to-make-specified-area-of-an-image-transparent-with-imagick)

- adding a gradient at a certain area

It would look something like this:
`magick -size 256x128 -define gradient:radii=128,128 radial-gradient:black-white radial_gradient_maximum.png`

Look at [the help page](https://imagemagick.org/script/gradient.php)

- drawing on the images

Drawing a circle can be done like this:
`convert -size 81x81 xc:black -fill white -draw 'circle 40,40 40,3' circle_raw.png`

Drawing a pixel, line, symbol or circle is explained over at https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/